# How to make a sound like this?

Tags: sound-effects, music, production, fl-studio, electronic-music

I couldn't find how to make a sound like the one that starts at 0:58 :

Is there a plugin that enables how to do it or do you modify an instrument to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at snare samples? That's what it sounds like to me - a reversed snare sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a sampled 'aaah'(vocal), played in different keys. Just find a bit of vocals you like, drop it in a sampler, pitch it up by an octave or more and you;re ready. It may help to loop a few ms so that it stays more constant in pitch, timbre and amplitude. The amplitude envelope sounds like a sharp attack, no decay, full sustain and the tiniest bit of release.